# Install Samsung Galaxy S5 system on Star Note 3 (Samsung device clone)

Tags: rom-flashing

I had bought a Japanese phone that seems to be rooted, but the Android version of the root is very buggy. So, I wanted to change it to the system of the Galaxy S5. I was wondering was it possible? I believe the phone is a Star N9800 Note 3 Style running on Android 4.4

Comment: You can load a custom rom (if the bootloader is unlocked).  What have you tried?  What are you looking for from us?

Comment: I just realized that your phone **is not Samsung Galaxy Note 3**, but **Star Note 3**, a Samsung clone. Edited to clarify the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The system of the s5, also it is a note 3?
Boot your phone into recovery mode (youtube how to do this for your specific model)
Assuming there is no custom recovery installed, wipe the phone to factory settings and it should remove the root and revert the phone to stock.
Alternatively, you could add a custom recovery to it, and flash a new ROM